# C++ : Any possibility to declare a struct in main.cpp but having a template with class in header

Tags: c++, class, templates, struct

As a beginner in C++ with templates I have a question, sorry if it's ridiculous.

With having a template in header file like this one:

```
template <class T> class MyClass
```

is it possible to define a structure in the main.cpp like this:

```
struct CC;

struct CC
{

     MyClass (CC) p;
     CC() : p(0){}
};
```

Or :

```
struct Foo {

    MyClass<struct Foo> bar;
    MyClass<std::string> text;
};
```

I am very lost at this. Sorry.

Comment: Have you tried yet? By the way, c++ do not need to use `struct Foo` but can use `Foo` in your `MyClass<>`

Comment: It depends on `MyClass`. If it anywhere requires the template parameter to be a complete class (i.e. that `sizeof` can be applied), then no. Because the `CC` or `Foo` class is not complete at the point where it's used as template argument.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I did not understand...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, whether the template is in a header file or not, does not matter. The compiler proper only sees the code after preprocessing, and at that point there are no files. Just text.

Let's consider a variation of your first example:

```
template< class T >
class MyClass
{
    int x;
};

struct CC
{

     MyClass<CC> m;
     CC() {}
}; 

auto main() -> int {}
```

This compiles fine because the `MyClass` template doesn't actually use `CC` for anything, and so no knowledge of it other than that it's a type, is needed.

But let's say that its size is used. That requires a **complete type**. Or put another way, a complete type *is* a type whose size is known.

```
template< class T >
class MyClass
{
    char x[sizeof( T )];
};

struct CC
{

     MyClass<CC> m;
     CC() {}
}; 

auto main() -> int {}
```

This shall not compile, because at the point where `MyClass<CC>` is used, the size of `CC` is not yet known. Additional data members, or e.g. a virtual function, could be defined later in the class definition. That would increase the size.

---

As a near counter-example, consider this third variant:

```
template< class T >
class MyClass
{
public:
    void foo()
    {
        char x[sizeof( T )];
    }
};

struct CC
{

     MyClass<CC> m;
     void use_foo() { m.foo(); }
     CC() {}
}; 

auto main() -> int {}
```

This compiles fine, but why? Apparently also here the template requires a complete `CC` type?

But no, the compiler treats member function definitions in a class as if they'd been declared `inline` and defined outside of the class, like this:

```
template< class T >
class MyClass
{
public:
    inline void foo();
};

template< class T >
void MyClass<T>::foo()
{
    char x[sizeof( T )];
}

struct CC
{

     MyClass<CC> m;
     inline void use_foo();
     CC() {}
}; 

void CC::use_foo() { m.foo(); }

auto main() -> int {}
```

And from this you can see that the `MyClass` template itself does not depend on knowledge of the size of `CC`.